# Using cut function on data.table for dates

Tags: r, datetime, data.table, lubridate

I'm trying to figure out the best way to achieve my goal. I have one large master data.table (>110,000 observations) that contains data from photos taken by several camera stations. I have a separate data.table that holds information about these cameras, like when photos were uploaded from them (photos were uploaded from each camera multiple times). For each camera, I need to subset the photos taken by it into "bins" that are defined by when the photos were uploaded. I assume that I will need to use a `for` loop to run through each camera but from there I get stuck. I feel like I am looking for a version of the cut function that can return what "bin" the photo belongs in as a separate column in the data.table.

Example data.table of the photos from one camera:

```
> station_photos
 year_unit_station    Photo_Number   Creation_Datetime bin_name
1:       2016_275_02 275_02_0017.JPG 2016-09-23 11:51:03         
2:       2016_275_02 275_02_0035.JPG 2016-09-27 15:58:21         
3:       2016_275_02 275_02_0036.JPG 2016-09-27 15:58:49         
4:       2016_275_02 275_02_0037.JPG 2016-09-27 16:00:04         
5:       2016_275_02 275_02_0038.JPG 2016-09-27 16:00:59         
6:       2016_275_02 275_02_0039.JPG 2016-09-27 16:01:27         
7:       2016_275_02 275_02_0062.JPG 2016-10-02 12:22:35         
>
```

Example of the table that shows when the photos were uploaded:

```
> station_bins
   year_unit_station    service_end_dttm      bin_name
1:       2016_275_02 2016-09-23 11:21:00 2016_275_02_1
2:       2016_275_02 2016-09-30 10:45:00 2016_275_02_2
3:       2016_275_02 2016-10-07 08:31:00 2016_275_02_3
```

End goal table for each camera that I am hoping to get from my code:

```
> station_photos
 year_unit_station    Photo_Number   Creation_Datetime bin_name
1:       2016_275_02 275_02_0017.JPG 2016-09-23 11:51:03 2016_275_02_1        
2:       2016_275_02 275_02_0035.JPG 2016-09-27 15:58:21 2016_275_02_1        
3:       2016_275_02 275_02_0036.JPG 2016-09-27 15:58:49 2016_275_02_1        
4:       2016_275_02 275_02_0037.JPG 2016-09-27 16:00:04 2016_275_02_1       
5:       2016_275_02 275_02_0038.JPG 2016-09-27 16:00:59 2016_275_02_1        
6:       2016_275_02 275_02_0039.JPG 2016-09-27 16:01:27 2016_275_02_1        
7:       2016_275_02 275_02_0062.JPG 2016-10-02 12:22:35 2016_275_02_2
8:       2016_275_02 275_02_0075.JPG 2016-10-31 03:09:43 2016_275_02_3        
>
```

I've considered using `cut()` or `subset` but I am not sure how to get either to fill in that last variable of the "bin_name" for me rather than just returning a list or data.frame. My other concern is that not every camera will have 3 bins, some will have 2 some will have 4. And to add one more twist to this how could I use a similar or the same method to create bins that are a set length rather than from a date range. The end goal is to count how many photos were taken by the camera between uploads as well as to count the number of photos taken by each camera in 10 minute intervals. It would be very helpful to still have that bin_name column for future analysis.

I'm not really sure if my explanation makes sense and it is quite possible that I am making the solution way more complicated than I need to. Thank you in advance for any help or insight you can give!

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps, I have misunderstood the whole question but  I am wondering why the timestamp of the upload is *before* the timestamps of the photos in the bin, e.g., for bin `2016_275_02_1` the `service_end_dttm` was 2016-09-23 11:21:00 but the first photo in that bin was taken half an hour later at `Creation_Datetime` 2016-09-23 11:51:03.

However, OP's expected result can be reproduced by a *rolling join* and an *update by reference* with [data.table](/questions/tagged/data.table).

```
library(data.table)
station_photos[, bin_name := 
                 station_bins[station_photos, 
                              on = c("year_unit_station", "service_end_dttm" = "Creation_Datetime"), 
                              roll = Inf, bin_name]][]
```

> ```
>    year_unit_station    Photo_Number   Creation_Datetime      bin_name
> 1:       2016_275_02 275_02_0017.JPG 2016-09-23 11:51:03 2016_275_02_1
> 2:       2016_275_02 275_02_0035.JPG 2016-09-27 15:58:21 2016_275_02_1
> 3:       2016_275_02 275_02_0036.JPG 2016-09-27 15:58:49 2016_275_02_1
> 4:       2016_275_02 275_02_0037.JPG 2016-09-27 16:00:04 2016_275_02_1
> 5:       2016_275_02 275_02_0038.JPG 2016-09-27 16:00:59 2016_275_02_1
> 6:       2016_275_02 275_02_0039.JPG 2016-09-27 16:01:27 2016_275_02_1
> 7:       2016_275_02 275_02_0062.JPG 2016-10-02 12:22:35 2016_275_02_2
> 8:       2016_275_02 275_02_0075.JPG 2016-10-31 03:09:43 2016_275_02_3
> ```

#### Data

It was a bit tricky to convert the printed sample data into data.table objects to work with:

```
library(data.table)
library(magrittr)

station_photos <- "
   year_unit_station    Photo_Number   Creation_Datetime bin_name
1:       2016_275_02 275_02_0017.JPG 2016-09-23 11:51:03
2:       2016_275_02 275_02_0035.JPG 2016-09-27 15:58:21
3:       2016_275_02 275_02_0036.JPG 2016-09-27 15:58:49
4:       2016_275_02 275_02_0037.JPG 2016-09-27 16:00:04
5:       2016_275_02 275_02_0038.JPG 2016-09-27 16:00:59
6:       2016_275_02 275_02_0039.JPG 2016-09-27 16:01:27
7:       2016_275_02 275_02_0062.JPG 2016-10-02 12:22:35
8:       2016_275_02 275_02_0075.JPG 2016-10-31 03:09:43" %>% 
  readr::read_fwf(col_types = "-ccc") %>% 
  setDT() %>% 
  setnames(.[1, unlist(.SD)]) %>% 
  .[-1] %>% 
  .[, Creation_Datetime := anytime::anytime(Creation_Datetime)]

station_bins <- "
   year_unit_station    service_end_dttm      bin_name
1:       2016_275_02 2016-09-23 11:21:00 2016_275_02_1
2:       2016_275_02 2016-09-30 10:45:00 2016_275_02_2
3:       2016_275_02 2016-10-07 08:31:00 2016_275_02_3" %>% 
  readr::read_fwf(col_types = "-ccc") %>% 
  setDT() %>% 
  setnames(.[1, unlist(.SD)]) %>% 
  .[-1] %>% 
  .[, service_end_dttm := anytime::anytime(service_end_dttm)]
```

Comment: Sorry the data was a little tough to get in a usable format, I am still new to posting questions on here. If you have suggestions on how to put up sample data I'm open to them.

As to your date question, that date is when the camera was first turned on and I was using that 'start time' as the label for each bin. This would mean that photos in the 2016_275_02_1 bin were taken between that bin's timestamp and the next bin's time stamp.

I don't know anything about rolling joins or updating by reference, I will definitely give this a try! My other solution was way less elegant.